# 301 redirect for OpenCart (old url to new)

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I am looking for a 301 redirect. I have a OC 1.5.1.3 (abc.com) and have a new store now on OC 2.0.3.1 (xyz.com ). I have migrated my data from abc.com to xyz.com and since all the product / pages urls are the same except the domain change, i am looking for a simple code which i can add to htaccess to make this happen.

Since my old website urls are listed on Google, i would like to redirect the traffic coming to a particular url to the same page on the new website. It would be a permanent redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I paid a freelancer to get this done.. was in a hurry. Anyways, i have posted the answer below for the benefit of all.

Upload this to .htaccess on your old domain abc.com, replace example.com with your new domain name.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```